# Invalid command 'SSLRequireSSL',

Tags: apache-2.2, svn

An svn server that I managed crashed.  The server is up and running again, but I can't manage to get svn running anymore.

I followed the instructions listed here:  http://mark.koli.ch/2010/03/howto-setting-up-your-own-svn-server-using-apache-and-mod-dav-svn.html

Yet when I try to start apache using /etc/init.d/httpd start I get a [FAILED] message.  There is no content in the error logs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: post added configuration, check directory path exists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That instruction set didn't include `SSLEngine On`, which is needed if you're gonna require SSL, as well as a working `SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLCertificateKeyFile`.

Do you even want/need SSL? If not, just remove the `SSLRequireSSL` directive.